# Can't Change UIView Height When KeyboardDidHide is called

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints, frame

Any idea why I cannot change the height of my containerView when KeyboardDidHide notification happens? The height changes in KeyboardDidShow perfectly fine but won't change back in KeyboardDidHide. Also, it does change back if I change it in TextFieldDidEndEditing but that doesn't work quite perfectly for what I need.

```
func setupKeyboardObserver() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardDidShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardDidHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)
}

@objc func handleKeyboardDidHide() {
    if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        if UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436 {
            containerView.frame.size.height += 35
        }
    }
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        if UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436 {
            containerView.frame.size.height += 35
        }
    }
}

@objc func handleKeyboardDidShow() {

    if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        if UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436 {
            containerView.frame.size.height -= 35
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it because of the condition `if UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436` ?

Comment: @Amit No, it reaches the code. If you print the height you get the height it should be it just doesn't visually change

Answer (score 0):

Try `layoutIfNeeded()` after setting new height value.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code after you have set containerView height

```
containerView.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Hope will helpful to you